# Заполнение структуры данных по пакету из сети

Tags: c#

Имеется стороннее приложение, выдающее в сеть пакеты известной конфигурации. В приложении на C/C++ достаточно просто скопировать `sizeof` байт (с учетом упаковки по 1 байту и одинакового порядка байт на разных сторонах сети) из принятого буфера в экземпляр структуры. А как быть в C#?

Допустим, я принял пакет данных через [`UdpClient.Receive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive(v=vs.110).aspx). Как его наиболее благоприятным образом преобразовать в удобный для дальнейшей обработки вид? [`BinaryReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx)? [`Marshal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.110).aspx)? Как-то иначе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хоть через BinaryReader, хоть через свой кастомный сериализатор.

Если вы принимаете UDP пакеты, они как правило представляют собой законченные пакеты. Если нет ручной фрагментации или протокол приема/передачи не предусматривает дополнительных данных (ID команды или отправителя например), то  можно в самой структуре написать сериализатор и просто загонять принятый массив байт как параметр в конструкторе.

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под термином `кастомный сериализатор`?

Comment: Например, у меня есть свой BinaryWriter/BinaryReader на unsafe функциях, работающий в 2 раза быстрее нативного, есть такой же но на обычных функциях, работающий на 40% быстрее нативного.

Comment: За счет чего он работает быстрее?

Comment: За счет того, что написан не криво. Вы же не думаете, что все что есть в dotNet написано максимально эффективно. У меня и хеш коллекции (Dictionary, HashTable) свои которые работают в 2-2,5 раза быстрее нативных. Если у вас гит не заблокирован, вот вам ссылка  https://github.com/LuchunPen/Fast-Hash-Collection

Comment: Просто я не вижу причин, коду из библиотечных классов не быть максимально эффективным, коли уж можно на коленке создать что-то в разы лучше. Ну это так, лирическое отступление, Ваш код пока не смотрел.

Comment: Не все можно сделать в разы эффективнее. Например нативный List я не смог переплюнуть, как и встроенную сортировку, а за массивы даже браться не хочу. Да и даже те библиотечные вещи которые можно написать более эффективно, достаточно неплохо написаны. С другой стороны каждый день изобретаются какие то более лучшие решения, даже вы, написав сегодня небольшую программу, вполне возможно. через месяц, год сможете написать ее более совершенную аналогию. Да и могу вас заверить, что есть более эффективная версия моего кода, просто писал ее человек с гораздо большим чем у меня опытом )).

Answer (score 2):

Если хочется использовать способ, максимально похожий на C/C++, то пометить структуру атрибутом [StructLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), разметить поля атрибутами `FieldOffset` и можно мапить с помощью `Marshal.PtrToStructure`.

Comment: Я так понимаю, в данном случае придется аллоцировать/деаллоцировать неуправляемую память в процессе таких преобразований. Хорошо ли это?

Comment: @alexolut - Это хуже (медленнее), чем в C++, но лучше (быстрее), чем использовать `BinaryReader`.

Comment: А какой всё-таки способ может считаться стандартным для такого рода задач? Есть какие-то рекомендации на этот счет от авторитетов C#?

Comment: @alexolut - В дотнете стандартом считается безопасный (управляемый) код. То есть без указателей, без маршализации и т. п. То есть BinaryReader.